# Proof of Ito's Identity using Ito's formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

**Prove**
$\int_{0}^{t} W_s dW_s=1/2 {W_t}^2-1/2t$ using Ito's formulas.

I don't really know how to approach this problem since I'm not given a function to find it's derivatives and plug into the Ito's formula which is:

$Y_t=f(0,0)+\int_{0}^{t}[\frac{df}{dx}(s,W_s)]dW_s+\int_{0}^{t}[\frac{df}{dt}(s,W_s)+\frac{1d^2f}{2dx^2}(s,W_s)]ds$

**If I was given some function what I would do is:**

1. Find partial derivatives required,
2. Plugin into the formula
3. Play about with it until I get the required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.math.hcmuns.edu.vn/~dmduc/lop%20giao%20su%20nuoc%20ngoai/Oksendal%20-%20Stochastic%20differential%20equations%20%20(book)(6ed.,%20Springer,%202003)(385s).pdf), Page $45$, example 4.1.3.

Comment: So you do have to pick a function in order to compute this...

Comment: Well.. yes, you do have to do something.