# Ito's Lemma applied to the Solution to the General Linear Equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

When I apply Ito's lemma to the solution of the general linear equation I don't get the correct result.

Starting with the general linear equation,

$dX_t=\left( a(t)X+c(t)\right) dt + \left( b(t)X+d(t)\right)dW_t$

The solution is

$X(t,W_t)=\Phi(t,W_t) I(t,W_t)$

$\Phi(t,W_t)=\exp\left(\int_{0}^{t}{\left( a(s) - \frac{1}{2}b^2(s)\right) ds}+\int_{0}^{t}{b(s)dW_s}\right)$

$I(t,W_t)=X_0 + \int_{0}^{t}{\Phi^{-1}\left( c(t)-b(t)d(t)\right)ds}+\int_{0}^{t}{\Phi^{-1}d(s)dW_s}$

Applying Ito's lemma to the solution,

$d\left(\Phi I\right)=Id\Phi+\Phi dI+dI d\Phi$

When I compute each term I get

$d\Phi=a(t) \Phi dt + b(t) \Phi dW_t$

$dI=\Phi^{-1}\left( c(t) - b(t)d(t)\right) dt + \Phi^{-1}d(t) dW_t -\frac{1}{2}\Phi^{-1}b(t)d(t) dt $

$=\Phi^{-1}\left( c(t) - \frac{3}{2}b(t)d(t)\right) dt + \Phi^{-1}d(t) dW_t $

Putting these into Ito's lemma,

$dX_t=\left( a(t)X+c(t)-\frac{1}{2}b(t)d(t)\right) dt + \left( b(t)X+d(t)\right)dW_t$

This is off by the term $-\frac{1}{2}b(t)d(t) dt$. I believe that my expression for dI is off but I'm not certain where the mistake is.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Comparing your $\Phi(t,B_t)$ with the [usual suspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Linear_SDE:_General_case) it looks wrong. Also: writing $\Phi$ and $I$ as being functions of $B_t$ is wrong. They are functions of the entire Brownian path.

Comment: The last term is $b(t)$ not $d(t)$, thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo, it doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: It surely does not. I pointed out other things that are wrong. Again: $\Phi$ depends on $\int_0^tb(s)\,d\color{red}{B}_s\,.$ Given the WP link it is a mechanical exercise to fix your formulas. I hope you don't want me to do that.

Comment: You pointed out a typ0, I thanked you for that, and corrected my post. The question still remains. If you can point out where my result is incorrect, I would greatly appreciate that help.

Comment: Your result is incorrect because you are still starting with the wrong expression for $\Phi\,.$ I will not point out further details. Take WP and mechanically translate their notation in to yours. Even better: take their notation, forget your notation and apply Ito.

Comment: My expression for $\Phi$ is the exact same as in WP, it is equivalent to Kloeden p.112, and  Gardiner p. 109.

Comment: I do not know what you are looking at. In WP I see
$$
\Phi_t=\color{red}{\exp}\left(\int_0^t\left(a(s)-\tfrac{b^2(s)}{2}\right)\,ds+\int_0^tb(s)\,dW_s\right)\,.
$$
Even after numerous edits in OP that has at least *four* differences to your $\Phi\,.$

Comment: I've put the definitions in the WP form you suggest rather that the Kloeden or Gardiner versions. The application of Ito's lemma is not dependent on this and the original question remains.

Comment: Looks better. Now we can look at your calculations. The term $-\frac{1}{2}\Phi^{-1}b(t)d(t) dt$ in $$dI=\Phi^{-1}\left( c(t) - b(t)d(t)\right) dt + \Phi^{-1}d(t) dW_t -\frac{1}{2}\Phi^{-1}b(t)d(t) dt$$ should not be there. You just "differentiate" an integral. That is not even Ito's formula. I would not be surprised if this resolves the entire issue.

Comment: From Ito's formula<br/>
$dI=I_t dt+I_W dW + \frac{1}{2} I_{WW} dt$<br/>

$I_{W}=\Phi^{-1}d(t)$<br/>

$I_{WW}=\Phi^{-1}d(t)(-b(t))$<br/>

This makes the third term in $dI$<b/r>

$-\frac{1}{2}\Phi^{-1}b(t)d(t)$<br/>

Comment: It does not. $I$ is just a sum of two integrals and not a function of $W_t$ that you can differentiate. I criticised that notation in my very first comment. Something you never addressed. I wish I could downvote that post once more.

Comment: By your reasoning $I=\int_{0}^{t}{W_t dW_t}$ is not a function of $W_t$ that can be differentiated. Any yet, $I_{W_t}=W_t$, $I_{{W_t}{W_t}}=1$, and $dI=\frac{1}{2}dt+W_t dW_t$.

Comment: For that example we have [as we know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546484/proof-of-itos-identity-using-itos-formula) $I_t=\frac{W_t^2-t}{2}$ and $dI_t=W_t\,dW_t\,.$

Answer (score 1):

With your finally correct definitions but with better notation
$$
\Phi_t=\textstyle\exp\left(\int_0^t( a - \frac{1}{2}b^2)\,\mathrm{d}s+\int_0^tb\,\mathrm{d}W_s\right)\,,
$$
$$
I_t=X_0 + \int_0^t\frac{(c-b\,d)\,\mathrm ds+d\,\mathrm dW_s}{\Phi_s}
$$
we have

> $$\mathrm{d}\Phi_t=a\,\Phi_t\,\mathrm{d}t+b\,\Phi_t\,\mathrm{d}W_t\,,\quad\mathrm{d}I_t=\frac{(c - b\,d)\,\mathrm{d}t + d\,\mathrm{d}W_t}{\Phi_t}\,,\quad \mathrm{d}\langle I,\Phi\rangle_t=b\,d\,\mathrm{d}t\,,\quad X_t=\Phi_t\,I_t\,.$$\begin{align}\mathrm{d}X_t&=I_t\,\mathrm{d}\Phi_t+\Phi_t\,\mathrm{d}I_t+\mathrm{d}\langle I,\Phi\rangle_t\\[2mm]&=X_t(a\,\mathrm{d}t+b\,\mathrm{d}W_t)+(c-b\,d\,\mathrm{d}t)\,\mathrm{d}t+d\,\mathrm{d}W_t+b\,d\,\mathrm dt\\[2mm]&=(aX_t+c)\,\mathrm{d}t+(bX_t+d)\,\mathrm{d}W_t\end{align}

as expeted.